# Retrieving a subset of XML nodes with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Using PHP, how do I get an entire subset of nodes from an XML document? I can retrieve something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<people>
  <certain>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <age>21</age>
  </certain>
  <certain>
  <certain>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <age>34</age>
  </certain>
</people>
```

But what if I only want to return the child nodes of  like this?

```
  <certain>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <age>21</age>
  </certain>
  <certain>
  <certain>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <age>34</age>
  </certain>
```

EDIT: I'm trying to get a subset of XML and pass that directly, not an object like simplexml would give me. I am basically trying to get PHP to do what .NET's OuterXml does... return literally the above subset of XML as is... no interpreting or converting or creating a new XML file or anything... just extract those nodes in situ and pass them on. Am I going to have to get the XML file, parse out what I need and then rebuild it as a new XML file? If so then I need to get rid of the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` bit... ugh.

Comment: Do you want to import the elements into another document? (Because you need exactly one root element for a well-formed xml document, not two <certain> elements...)

Comment: Yes. I want to import however many <certain> elements exist in the document. Actually, I am wrapping retrieved data in a new node (because I need to fill the node with different data depending on a variety of factors. So I'll return something like <results><certain></certain><certain></certain></results>

Comment: I have updated my answer assuming that you want to copy some nodes from a document to another (your wrapper thing.) I don't know what NET's OuterXml, but judging by the name it would return the <people/> node as well, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer would be to use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp).

```
$people = simplexml_load_string(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <people>
      <certain>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <age>21</age>
      </certain>
      <certain>
        <name>John Smith</name>
        <age>34</age>
      </certain>
    </people>'
);

// get all <certain/> nodes
$people->xpath('//certain');

// get all <certain/> nodes whose <name/> is "John Smith"
print_r($people->xpath('//certain[name = "John Smith"]'));

// get all <certain/> nodes whose <age/> child's value is greater than 21
print_r($people->xpath('//certain[age > 21]'));
```

---

### Take 2

So apparently you want to copy some nodes from a document into another document? SimpleXML doesn't support that. [DOM](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) has methods for that but they're kind of annoying to use. Which one are you using? Here's what I use: [SimpleDOM](http://code.google.com/p/simpledom/). In fact, it's really SimpleXML augmented with DOM's methods.

```
include 'SimpleDOM.php';
$results = simpledom_load_string('<results/>');

foreach ($people->xpath('//certain') as $certain)
{
    $results->appendChild($certain);
}
```

That routine finds all `<certain/>` node via XPath, then appends them to the new document.

Comment: Josh, thanks for the response. I edited the question to clarify. If you can take a look amd see if that helps explain what I'm trying to do I'd appreciate it.

Comment: SimpleDOM looks interesting but I cannot add it to the mix on this project. I'll look into using DOM to do the whole thing (and if you have any tips on doing it that way or can point me in the right direction that would be great).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`DOMDocument.GetElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) **or you could:**

**Use XPath?**

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

$result = $xml->xpath("//certain");

print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: This gives me an object. I am trying to get a subset of the XML to pass directly to the function. It looks like I might have to read the XML, parse it, then recreate the XML! Ugh. I hope there is an easier way. basically I want to extract <certain><name>blah</name><age>2</age></certain> and return precisely that, not an object or a new XML document... just that bit. Like OuterXml would do in .NET

Answer (score 2):

Use DOM and XPath. Xpath allows you to select nodes (and values) from an XML DOM.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$result = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/people/certain') as $node) {
  $result .= $dom->saveXml($node);
}

echo $result;
```

Demo: https://eval.in/162149

DOMDocument::saveXml() has a context argument. If provided it saves that node as XML. Much like `outerXml()`. PHP is able to register your own classes for the DOM nodes, too. So it is even possible to add an `outerXML()` function to element nodes.

```
class MyDomElement extends DOMElement {
  public function outerXml() {
    return $this->ownerDocument->saveXml($this);
  }
}

class MyDomDocument extends DOMDocument {
  public function __construct($version = '1.0', $encoding = 'utf-8') {
    parent::__construct($version, $encoding);
    $this->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'MyDomElement');
  }
}

$dom = new MyDomDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$result = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/people/certain') as $node) {
  $result .= $node->outerXml();
}

echo $result;
```

Demo: https://eval.in/162157

Comment: I added the answer to this (old) question, because a current one was marked a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be a combination of the xpath suggestion and outputting with `asXML()`.

Using the example given by Josh Davis:

```
$people = simplexml_load_string(
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <people>
          <certain>
            <name>Jane Doe</name>
            <age>21</age>
          </certain>
          <certain>
            <name>John Smith</name>
            <age>34</age>
          </certain>
        </people>'
    );

    // get all <certain/> nodes
    $nodes = $people->xpath('/people/certain');

    foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
      $result .= $node->asXML()."\n";
    }
    echo $result;
```