# PHP DOMDOCUMENT getNamedItem

Tags: php, domdocument

Here I am echoing out class elements from a webpage that I require (= 'titre'), but how do I echo out their value? Can't seem to make it work.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.spoofedwebpage.int/notice/search/wanted');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');  // Sample to get div element
$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');  // Sample to get div element


$i = 0;
while($span = $spans->item($i++))
{
    $class_node = $span->attributes->getNamedItem('class');
    if($class_node)
    {
        if($class_node->value == "titre")
        {   
        echo "Class is : " . $span->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->value . 
"<br>";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class attributes are a little special, because they are token lists (several class names seperated by whitespace), However I suggest you use Xpath to fetch the nodes:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
  <div class="titre foo">abc</div>
  <span class="titre bar">def</span> 
  <div class="bar">hij</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$expression = '//*[(self::div or self::span) and contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " titre ")]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  echo "Text is: ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

Output: https://eval.in/162248

```
Text is: abc
Text is: def
```

About the expression:

Select any element in the document ...

`//*`

... if it is a `div` or `span` ...

`//*[(self::div or self::span)]`

... and the `class` attribute contains a class name `titre`

`//*[
  (self::div or self::span) and 
  contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " titre ")
]`

`normalize-space()` takes a string and converts all whitespace groups into single spaces. It strips whitespaces from the start and end of the string too. `concat` is used to add a single space to the start and the end of the normalized string. The result is a string of class names like *SPACE CLASS_ONE SPACE CLASS_TWO SPACE*. This allows it to look for a substring like *SPACE CLASS_ONE SPACE*.

**btw** Are you sure that you're looking for `titre` and not `title`?

**HINT** The original answer selected the class attributes, see the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24205492/revisions) if you're interested in it.

Comment: Hi ThW, thanks so much for the excellent detailed response, I'll work on it now. The website class is 'titre' but its a good question.

Comment: Hi ThW, that works well but I want to find the value of the class element. For example if the element is <p class="titre">This is the text</p>, what I want to display is 'This is the text'. ThW

Comment: This is not the value of the class element. Here is no class element, the div and span are element nodes. So the answer is simple remove the `/@class` from the expression (selecting the element nodes) and read the $nodeValue from them. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks ThW, I must say I'm impressed, you certainly know your way around XPATH / Dom, I'll make notes and use this method going forward.Thanks again.

Comment: Hi ThW, one more quick question, I have the data I need now, but if the data exists on the webpage seperated by a HTML tag (e.g.<b><br>) or a space, I'm losing the tag or the space. For example 'John F <br>Kennedy' would be echoing as 'JohnFKennedy', I've been playing with other Xref expressions to try to rectify this, with no success. You seem very familiar, have you experienced this issue?

Comment: DOMDocument::saveXml() can be used to get a node as XML. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24201049/2265374